# ¿Cómo comprobar que un dataset contiene filas en C# Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Estoy realizando un programa en C#, y hoy me he encontrado con el siguiente problema. Necesito introducir en un StringBuilder datos que provienen de un dataset:

```
StringBuilder sbGeneracionConstruccionFont = new StringBuilder();
int idFont = Convert.ToInt32(dtFuente["IdFont"].ToString());
DataSet dsDatosFont = AccesoDatosGenerico.EjecutaQuery(oConexion, "SELECT * FROM dat_fonts_1 WHERE Operacion<>'B' AND IdEmpresa=" + oBalanza.IdEmpresa + " AND IdConfiguracion=" + oBalanza.IdConfiguracion + " AND IdFontAsociado = "+idFont);
```

Pero este dataset puede venir sin filas, por lo que casuaría un NullPointerException. ¿Bastaría con esta instrucción?:

```
if(dsDatosFont_t_b != null)
            {
                sbGeneracionConstruccionFont.Append(dsDatosFont.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SectoresInicioFont"].ToString());

            }
```

¿O hay alguna forma de comprobar que el dataset contiene filas? He estado intentado esto último, pero parece que los métodos y atributos proporcionados en DataSet no lo hacen. ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener el número de filas? Gracias

Comment: Puedes realizar un ternario con [`DBNull.Value`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=net-5.0) esto comprueba si lo que has recibido es nulo con un retorno booleano

Comment: `dsDatosFont.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SectoresInicioFont"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dsDatosFont.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SectoresInicioFont"].ToString()`

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas comprobar que el objeto de donde obtienes el valor no llega vacío.

```
    if (dsDatosFont != null
                && (dsDatosFont.Tables["dat_fonts_1"] != null)
                && (dsDatosFont.Tables["dat_fonts_1"].Rows.Count > 0)
                && (from r in dsDatosFont.Tables["dat_fonts_1"].Rows[0].ItemArray.OfType<DataRow>() where r["SectoresInicioFont"] != null select r).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                sbGeneracionConstruccionFont.Append(dsDatosFont.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SectoresInicioFont"].ToString());
            }
```